# Allow users to set branch policies but not Cross Repo Policies

Tags: azure, azure-devops

**Current situation (if I'm not missing anything)**

1. If Project settings --> Repos-->Repositories-> Git Repositories -> "Edit Policies" is allowed, users can edit Cross Repo Policies and add "local" policies to individual repos/branches
2. If Project settings --> Repos-->Repositories-> Git Repositories -> "Edit Policies" is denied , users can't edit any kind of policies (Cross Repo or "local")
3. If I want users to be able to edit "local" policies on specific repos/branches but not be able to edit Cross Repo Policies, I have to

   On "Git Repositories", set "Edit Policies" to Denied
   *On each Repository*, set "Edit Policies" to Allowed

**Desired behavior**
Is there a way to allow users to edit "Local" repository/branch policies without setting permissions on each individual repo?

Basically, I want to enforce the company wide "Cross Repo Policies" but allow teams to add additional policies own their own repos/branches if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Did it answer your question?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I meant to accept it but I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you described in above current situation is by design, and it is easy to understand. For the permissions you set for `Git Repositories` are Cross Repo, they apply to all the repos in the project.

So that if you allow the edit policy permission for a user in `Git Repositories` level. He will be able to edit the Cross Repo Policies. If you deny the permission, he will not be edit any kind of policy.

When a user is added to a team group of the project. He will inherit the permission settings of this group. So you can set the `Edit Policies` permission to `Not set`  for a user on `Git Repositories` level. He will inherit the permission set for the group which he is a member of.

If you want to enforce the company wide "Cross Repo Policies" but allow teams to add additional policies own their own repos/branches if necessary. You will need to set the `Edit Policies` permission to `Deny` on `Git Repositories` level and set the `Edit Policies` permission to `allow` on each repo level for each individual team group.

Check the steps  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to add a team in azure devops.